# Is there a noun that means "non-fictional summary/description of a specific topic supported by external references"?

Tags: word-request, nouns

Basically the summary or description of one specific topic, where the description is non-fictional, backed by 3rd party references, and does not describe new ideas but instead only summarizes a topic using trusted references.

Comment: Maybe "abstract"? In which context do you need this word? Please give an example.

Comment: @virolino I'm making a school project (website) where a page represents a "topic" of interest to our group. For example the pages "My local town name" or "Cheryl street" or "Name of local event" represent a "thing" and the page contains a "non-fictional summary/description of the topic" plus other metadata.

Comment: Introduction/Abstract?

Comment: "Overview"? "In a nutshell"? "About"? "Synopsis"? "Summary"? "Brief description"?

Comment: I don't think there's a word that combines both *summary* ***and*** *factual*. All synonyms I can think of can apply equally to fictional accounts.